# Need to prove trigonometric equation using definition of forward difference operator

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation

I am trying to prove

$ \triangle^{2}\sin(\log x)=2\cos(\log \sqrt{x^{2}+xh})\sin(\log\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x}}) $

Using definition of forward difference operator

$\triangle f(x)=f(x+h)−f(x) $

But I can't get my head around it, I have basic knowledge of interpolation which I think is not enough for proving this, can anybody help

Comment: Question is wrong. second order forward difference could not prove this equation but first order do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** I think instead of the second difference ($\Delta^2$) the question is about the first difference ($\Delta^1$). You may want to recheck your problem.

Using $\sin A -\sin B=2 \sin\frac{(A-B)}{2} \cos\frac{(A+B)}{2}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\Delta \sin(\log x) & =\sin(\log(x+h)) - \sin (\log x)\\
& = 2 \sin\left(\frac{\log(x+h)-\log x}{2}\right)  \, \cos\left(\frac{\log(x+h)+\log x}{2}\right)\\
& = 2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{x+h}{x}\right)\right)  \, 
\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\left((x+h)x\right)\right)\\
& = 2 \sin\left(\log\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x}}\right)  \, 
\cos\left(\log\sqrt{x^2+xh}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: you got it right

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $D$ be the linear operation mapping $f(x)$ to $f(x+h)$. Let $I$ be the linear operation mapping $f(x)$ to itself. Then,

$$\Delta=D-I$$

$$\Delta^2=(D-I)^2=D^2-2D+I^2$$

$$=D^2-2D+I$$

This means $\Delta^2$ sends $f(x)$ to $f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)$.

Comment: I got that part already from basic definitions but couldn't resolve the trigonometric and logarithm part

Comment: I just went through the calculations myself. The expression is wrong.

Comment: can you give me your final result for comparison

Comment: My final result is that your expression simplifies to $\sin(\ln |x+h|)+\sin (\frac{1}{|x|})$ which is not what we want.

Comment: There are some issues when the expression isn't defined, but that's what is simplifies to using $2\sin a cos b=\sin (a+b)+\sin (a-b)$.

Comment: Also because $x>0$ it actually simplifies to $\sin (\log (x+h))-\sin (\log x)$ . Again, there might be issues where sometimes one side or both are not defined. Either way this is $\Delta f$ not $\Delta^2 f$.